# What type of library does telegram android uses to download and upload files?

Tags: download, upload, telegram

Telegram android library handle very well network interruption, I want to use similar type of library for my projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check their TDLib library?
https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/

https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1download_file.html
https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1upload_file.html